# invalid column name "config_link" using ns2

Tags: webserver, ns2, round-robin

I am confused to fix this problem. When i execute the file the error looks like this:can you give any idea please?

> 

```
invalid command name "config_link"
>         while executing
>     "config_link 0 $i [expr {$bandwidth($i)}] $delay_ DropTail "
>         ("for" body line 2)
>         invoked from within
>     "for {set i 1} {$i<=$numSERVERS} {incr i} { 
>     config_link 0 $i [expr {$bandwidth($i)}] $delay_ DropTail 
>     }"
```

and the code where the error happen is:

```
#SOURCE − SERVER i
for {set i 1} {$i<=$numSERVERS} {incr i} { 
config_link 0 $i [expr {$bandwidth($i)}] $delay_ DropTail 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

> invalid command name "config_link"

'config_link´ , 'config-link´ or similar is not included in any ns2 / any patch, AFAIK.

Example including "[expr {$bandwidth($i)}] $delay_ DropTail" : 
[https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=[expr+{%24bandwidth(%24i)}]+%24delay_+DropTail](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=[expr%20%7B%24bandwidth(%24i)%7D]%20%24delay_%20DropTail)
→ →  http://www.cs.odu.edu/~mweigle/papers/gelle-ms-proj-08.pdf

? May be you can upload your simulation-file.tcl to 'Google Docs' to know what you are trying to do.

---

Comment: If you can see my source code and the error there and you can give me an idea why this happen.     https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dYtS5pQ_bP91YNt28YR0DPslje6cyRfldtC2nsP4wxU/edit?pref=2&pli=1

Comment: See http://homepages.laas.fr/calbeasa/calbeasa/Publications_files/report.pdf ... Subroutines must be a separate file. "config_link" is defined in "subroutines.tcl",  which must be sourced as the first command in the main script. ...